# Update the column value sequentially in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a help in sql query for oracle database .

I am using a imaginary table here to explain the problem.

suppose we have customers table

[image: internal_counter, customer_name, customer_type 1 X Business 1 Y Retail 2 z Business]

so this internal counter is based on customer_type (i.e. for each customer type it begins from 1 till the max rows) . while doing testing I have updated the internal_counter to **null** .

[image]

now I want reassign the sequential number to them (for example Business customers) and I am not sure about below query .

```
DECLARE
    VAL NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN ( select * from customers where customer_type = 'Business' )
    LOOP
        UPDATE customers SET internal_counter = VAL ;       
        VAL := VAL +1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Do you think it's the right query?

I am asking here because I am not db expert and don't want to mess things further .

Comment: Just to comment, the inner part of the loop (with `update customers`) is not automatically linked to the outer part (`select * from customers`), so without some extra `where` clause it will update every row every time around the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use PL/SQL and loops; just do it in a single SQL query as it will be quicker and generate far fewer entries into the log files compared to running individual updates for each row:

```sql
MERGE INTO customers dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   customers
  WHERE  customer_type = 'Business'
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET internal_counter = src.rn;
```

---

However, if you have updated the values to `NULL` then the first thing to do is to try `ROLLBACK` and undo any changes you have made that are uncommitted as that may (if you have not used a `COMMIT` statement or any DDL statements) restore the pervious values.

Comment: @MTO I did COMMIT .

Answer (score 1):

Use a windowing function like ROW_NUMBER to generate your internal_counter, since it's not a simple sequential counter. Then feed that into an update of the table using the MERGE statement:

```
merge into customers
using (select rowid as rid,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_type ORDER BY customer_name) internal_counter
         from customers) src
on (customers.rowid = src.rid)
when matched then update set customers.internal_counter = src.internal_counter;
```